# Make Bottle return the correct response code, not a 200

Tags: http-headers, bottle

I'm trying to log output from a Bottle REST service using a custom logger. The problem is that Bottle error pages have a HTTP response code of 200 by default, so the logger always records `200 OK` since it looks at `response.status`.

I've tried making custom error handlers which set `response.status`, but that doesn't work.

Comment: I'm not understanding the problem. If you provide a minimal, working code snippet that demonstrates it, I'd be happy to take a look.

Answer (score 1):

The abort() function is a shortcut for generating HTTP error pages.

```
from bottle import route, abort
@route('/restricted')
def restricted():
    abort(401, "Sorry, access denied.")
```

Other than that, the HTTP status code (and other related info) is stored in an object called `response` up to the point where they are transmitted to the browser. You can manipulate the `Response.status` attribute  directly or use the predefined helper methods to do so.

The HTTP status code defaults to 200 OK. In most scenarios you won’t need to set the Response.status attribute manually, but use the abort() helper or return an HTTPResponse instance with the appropriate status code.

See [HTTP ERRORS AND REDIRECTS](https://bottlepy.org/docs/0.12/tutorial.html#http-errors-and-redirects) in the Tutorial docs.